# Правильно ли составлено сложноподчиненное предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, сложное-предложение

В приведенном ниже тексте вызывает сомнение структура выделенного СПП. Всё ли с ним в порядке?

Начиная с 1066 года, французский диалект нормандских завоевателей стал официальным языком поверженной Англии, и на этом языке предстояло говорить английским королям и правящим классам следующие триста лет. **Но англосаксонские крестьяне были слишком многочисленны и необразованны, чтобы пытаться навязать им новый язык,** и в любом случае среднестатистический англосакс использовал франко-нормандские слова только для того, чтобы продать свой товар аристократу или упросить солдата не кастрировать его за убийство ежика.

Answer (score 1):

> Начиная с 1066 года, французский диалект нормандских завоевателей стал
> официальным языком поверженной Англии, и на этом языке предстояло
> говорить английским королям и правящим классам следующие триста лет.

*Начиная с 1066 года* — оборот не о том, что сталось, или свершилось:

«*В 1066 году французский диалект нормандских завоевателей становится официальным языком поверженной Англии, на котором в последующие 300 лет будут говорить английские короли и правящие классы*».

> Но англосаксонские крестьяне были слишком многочисленны и необразованны, чтобы пытаться навязать им новый язык, и в любом случае среднестатистический англосакс использовал франко-нормандские слова только для того, чтобы продать свой товар аристократу или упросить солдата не кастрировать его за убийство ежика.

Комментировать второй абзац труднее, чем придать ему необходимую стройность:

«*Но не англосаксонские крестьяне, в массе необразованные, чтобы принять навязываемый язык, использующие франко-нормандские слова только для того, чтобы продать свой товар аристократу или упросить солдата не кастрировать за убийство ёжика*».

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.